# How to control mesh with rig with distortions

Tags: modeling, animation, weight-painting

I been doing a project for a couple months now relating to most of my questions I asked here and now I believe I only have one final problem.
I'm trying to rig a rectangle with a bendy bone and so far its been great, but when I rotate past certain degrees it breaks down terribly.

I would like to keep the mesh the same width no matter the pose like so:[image: Box reference drawings]

But this is the result for the 3d model:

[image: Twists]

The Twisting seems to be collapsing in on itself when around 180 degrees but on a simple twist it still looks concaved.

I would like to keep the sides consistent without the bottom section moving, is this even possible? It seems so simple but I never seen it before.

---pls feel free to edit the question I'm still new to blender after a few years so I don't know if this is a known topic or not.